# What happened to the second fake Goya painting?

Tags: tenet

I am talking about the fake Goya Painting, **which was handed over to The Protagonist by Sir Michael Crosby at restaurant**:

[image]

What happened to the second fake Goya painting ?

Comment: Please note that *Tenet* _is_ a movie, so there's no need to put the [tag:movie] tag on it.

Comment: @DavidW when to use **Movie** tag then?

Comment: @MaxwellKing - Usually where a property exists as a movie ***and in some other format*** (such as a book or comic). - Per the tag wiki "*This tag has three different uses: for questions specifically about the movie version of a work which has been adapted for different media (use together with the work tag); for questions seeking identification of a movie (use together with the [story-identification] tag); or for wider genre questions about movies as a whole (generally together with the [history-of] tag).*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear in [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/tenet-2020.pdf) after its appearance in the auction-house, nor is there any indication that it was actually auctioned.

A genuine Goya expert would have spotted that it's a fake (the implication is that she verified it as genuine due to her personal friendship with the forger, possibly as a favour or for monetary gain) and given that the purpose of Sir Michael Crosby handing over the painting was to help the Protagonist secure an introduction to the billionaire's wife and to demonstrate their hold over her, it was presumably taken back into possession by the British Secret Service in case of a future need to blackmail her.

You may want to note that MI5 don't value this picture especially highly. Sir Mike totes it around in a plastic bag, albeit one from Harrods. The Protagonist may have just disposed of it in the nearest waste bin.